# Deserialise JSON response from API into type in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm going out of my mind trying to figure this out because it's such a simple thing to do and there's no information on it anywhere.

I have an API call that is returning a `Student` which is defined like this

```
class Student {
  String photo;
  String upn;
  String fullName;
  String studentClass;
  String studentYear;
}
```

I'm using the dart http library to make a call to an API that returns an array of a number of students. All I want to do is deserialise the string returned by the API into a typed list so that I can actually do something with it.

```
studentFuture.then((res) {
              log(res.body.toString());
              List<dynamic> dynamicList = jsonDecode(res.body);
              var student = dynamicList[0] as Student;
            });
```

Trying to cast it to Student using `as` doesn't work, I just get this

`Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Student' in type cast`

All I want is to be able to do something like this like you can in C#

```
var obj = DeserialiseJson<Type>(jsonString);
```

No matter what I try I can't get the string to be deserialised into an object, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in Dart/Flutter in the way that you want. This is because in order to accomplish this functionality in C#, Java, or any other strongly-typed language that supports this feature, the language uses reflection under the hood to map JSON fields to object fields.

Dart also has reflection functionality in the `dart:mirror` library. However, this library is disabled in Flutter due to its tendency to create large app footprints due to all the debug information for various types and fields and things needing to be included in the compiled binary. (That's the very simple explanation: the official reason given by the Flutter team goes into more detail.)

What this means is when you deserialize a JSON string, you get an object that is essentially a `List<dynamic>` or `Map<String, dynamic>` (depending on the JSON string in question; it may even just be some primitive value). Assuming the latter, you cannot directly convert between a `Map` and a `Student` because they are completely different types with nothing in common. There is no implicit way to take the `Map` and generate a `Student` because the reflection tools necessary to do so don't exist within a Flutter app. As a result, you get an error saying you cannot convert a `Map` to a `Student`, as you can see.

To work around this, you are encouraged to add a `toJson/fromJson` method to your model class so you can explicitly generate an instance of the class from a deserialized JSON string:

```dart
class Student {
  String photo;
  String upn;
  String fullName;
  String studentClass;
  String studentYear;

  factory Student.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) {
    return Student()
      ..photo = jsonData['photo']
      ..upn = jsonData['upn']
      ..fullName = jsonData['fullName']
      ..studentClass = jsonData['studentClass']
      ..studentYear = jsonData['studentYear'];
  }
}
```

And use it like so:

```dart
studentFuture.then((res) {
  log(res.body.toString());
  List<dynamic> dynamicList = jsonDecode(res.body);
  var student = Student.fromJson(dynamicList[0]);
});
```

This is all well and good, but if you have more than a few model classes you will quickly realize that adding this boilerplate code to every model class gets really tedious really quick. That's why various packages exist to try and alleviate the burden with automatic code generation, such as [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) and [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed).

**TL;DR: What you are asking for is not currently possible in Flutter Dart, and that isn't likely to change any time soon. You need to either write a manual factory constructor to make the conversion or use a code-gen package that generates the constructors for you.**

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for, thank you. Is there any requirement to using a factory constructor rather than a regular one? Is it just for clarity?

Comment: @user9754798 In a nutshell, a regular constructor will already have the object created and you're just in charge of instantiating fields and performing other kinds of setup. A factory constructor allows you to manually create the object that you want to be returned to the site where the constructor was called. In your case it's mostly up to preference on which way to do it, but if your class had `final` fields (which being a model class it should) you couldn't instantiate the class fields using values from the `Map` in a normal constructor like you could in a factory constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable which, through code generation, will give you methods like

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class Student {
  String photo;
  String upn;
  String fullName;
  String studentClass;
  String studentYear;
  Student({this.photo, this.upn, this.fullName, this.studentClass, this.studentYear});
  factory Student.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$StudentFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$StudentToJson(this);
}
```

Then you can do:

```dart
var list = jsonDecode(res.body);
for (var map in list) {
  print(Student.fromJson(map)); // Student class
}
```